# AngularJS + Karma + Symfony : How to unit test directives when template is http-loaded from a twig template

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, symfony, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I am wondering what is the cleanest way to unit test AngularJS directives for which templateUrl refers to a Twig template returned by Symfony, for exemple:

```
directives.directive("myDirective", [function(){
    return{
        restriction: "E",
        templateUrl: 'http://server/symfony/templates/mytemplate'
    }
}]);
```

The problem is that $httpBackend is mocked by AngularJS Mock, so no http request is really sent, This problem is resolved using **ngHtml2JsPreprocessor** that will let link to real files without doing http requests.

But in my case, I have to do a true http request since the template is generated by Symfony, I cannot link to files directly.

Any idea? Thanks!